# Ошибка хранения адреса в указателе?

Tags: c++

Код:

```
int Europe_CountryCount=44;
int** nextWorldPart = new int*[6];
nextWorldPart[0]=&Europe_CountryCount;
```

Ошибка:

> ошибка: 'nextWorldPart' does not name a type
>   nextWorldPart[0]=&Europe_CountryCount;

Вышеуказанный код находится в .h файле.
Очистка и повторная сборка проекта - не помогли.

Comment: "Вышеуказанный код находится в .h файле." в какой-то функции или прямо в "глобальной" области?

Comment: nextWorldPart[0]=&Europe_CountryCount; Не является ни объявлением, ни определением. Это вызов оператора, который может быть выполнен только в функции.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите выделение памяти под массив и присвоение в основной cpp файл.
В .h будет:

```
int Europe_CountryCount=44;
int** nextWorldPart;
```

А в .cpp будет:

```
nextWorldPart = new int*[6];
nextWorldPart[0]=&Europe_CountryCount;
```

Comment: А вы считаете, что  название файлов  повлияет на общее правило?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я так сделал и этот кусок кода стал компилироваться.

Comment: может быть, но  правильно выполнить в функции.